# jqplot time above 24 hours

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I want to use jqplot to make a bar chart with values above 24:00 (hours), but the time goes to the following day.

If I have 23:00 it works fine, but when I have 25:00, it shows it as 1:00

Is there an option to use dateAxisRenderer with only hours and let it go on to the max of my data values?

Please some help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <link class="include" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.jqplot.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.min.css" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<?php 

$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours=array();
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['title']="my plot title";
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['07:00-08:00'] = '02:25:53';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['08:00-09:00']='16:34:37';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['09:00-10:00']='17:00:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['10:00-11:00']='17:00:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['11:00-12:00']='16:22:47';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['12:00-13:00']='16:00:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['13:00-14:00']='15:44:38';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['14:00-15:00']='15:00:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['15:00-16:00']='12:42:49';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['16:00-17:00']='01:38:06';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['17:00-18:00']='00:00:00';

$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['07:00-08:00']='00:00:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['08:00-09:00']='01:56:48';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['09:00-10:00']='03:54:20';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['10:00-11:00']='01:57:12';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['11:00-12:00']='04:36:33';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['12:00-13:00']='00:59:54';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['13:00-14:00']='02:56:38';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['14:00-15:00']='01:23:17';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['15:00-16:00']='02:32:50';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['16:00-17:00']='00:00:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['17:00-18:00']='25:00:25';

$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][0]='07:00-08:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][1]='08:00-09:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][2]='09:00-10:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][3]='10:00-11:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][4]='11:00-12:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][5]='12:00-13:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][6]='13:00-14:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][7]='14:00-15:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][8]='15:00-16:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][9]='16:00-17:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][10]='17:00-18:00';

echo "<pre>";
print_r($tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours);
echo "</pre>";

$chartname="chart1";
?>



<div id="chart1" style="height:400px; width:100%;"></div>


    <style type="text/css">
        #<?php echo $chartname; ?> .jqplot-point-label {
          color:#666666;
          font-size:14px;
        }                   
    </style>    
    <script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        <?php
                $js_array = json_encode($tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']);
                echo "var manhours = ". $js_array . ";\n";
                $w=json_encode($tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']);
                echo "var assignmenthours = ". $w . ";\n";
                $t=json_encode($tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks']);
                echo "var ticks = ". $t . ";\n";
        ?>

        var s1= new Array();
        for (var k in manhours){
            if (manhours.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                 //alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + manhours[k]);
                 s1.push(manhours[k]);
            }
        }

        var s2= new Array();
        for (var j in assignmenthours){
            if (assignmenthours.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                 //alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + manhours[k]);
                 s2.push(assignmenthours[j]);
            }
        }       

        // Can specify a custom tick Array.
        // Ticks should match up one for each y value (category) in the series.
       // var ticks = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'August'];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2], {
            // The "seriesDefaults" option is an options object that will
            // be applied to all series in the chart.
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
               pointLabels: { show: true },
                rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true}
            },
            // Custom labels for the series are specified with the "label"
            // option on the series option.  Here a series option object
            // is specified for each series.
            series:[
                {label:'Man-uren'},
                {label:'Opdracht uren'}
            ],
            // Show the legend and put it outside the grid, but inside the
            // plot container, shrinking the grid to accomodate the legend.
            // A value of "outside" would not shrink the grid and allow
            // the legend to overflow the container.
            legend: {
                show:true,
                placement: 'inside',
                rendererOptions: {
                    numberRows: 1
                },
                location:'ne',
                marginTop: '15px',
                marginRight: '30px'
            },
            axes: {
                // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: ticks
                },
                // Pad the y axis just a little so bars can get close to, but
                // not touch, the grid boundaries.  1.2 is the default padding.
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    pad: 1.05,
                   tickOptions: {
                      formatString: "%H:%M"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: If you use dateAxisRenderer it seams clear that 25h can not be displayed. If you want 25h00 to be display, use a classic axisRenderer and modify the label (i.e. if you have 25, add a 'h' suffix)

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, but how do i tho this? A nice solution would be to add an option to dateAxisRenderer (above24:true) and it counts on just in H:m:s. But as you say, I need a classic axisRenderer and modify the label. Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: You can do a preprocessing to build an array with your data values and then use this array as yaxis ticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indeed modifying the label did the trick, here the complete answer with all code i used to get this to work, so if anyone else that encountered this problem will have a full working example.

Instead of providing the data to the chart in H:i:s format, ill give it in seconds and process the seconds to a H:i:s format in the yaxis formatter.

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction. Shame that on most of those questions, no one will be making the effort to provide a full working example as answer, so her is mine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <link class="include" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.jqplot.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.min.css" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<?php 

$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours=array();
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['title']="my plot title";
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['07:00-08:00'] =34667;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['08:00-09:00']=261453;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['09:00-10:00']=273590;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['10:00-11:00']=272810;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['11:00-12:00']=257459;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['12:00-13:00']=252000;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['13:00-14:00']=250222;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['14:00-15:00']=241106;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['15:00-16:00']=210750;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['16:00-17:00']=23470;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']['17:00-18:00']=0;

$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['07:00-08:00']=0;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['08:00-09:00']=19907;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['09:00-10:00']=58960;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['10:00-11:00']=24520;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['11:00-12:00']=78638;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['12:00-13:00']=9576;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['13:00-14:00']=46201;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['14:00-15:00']=27642;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['15:00-16:00']=31582;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['16:00-17:00']=154;
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']['17:00-18:00']=1116;

$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][0]='07:00-08:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][1]='08:00-09:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][2]='09:00-10:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][3]='10:00-11:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][4]='11:00-12:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][5]='12:00-13:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][6]='13:00-14:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][7]='14:00-15:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][8]='15:00-16:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][9]='16:00-17:00';
$tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks'][10]='17:00-18:00';

echo "<pre>";
print_r($tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours);
echo "</pre>";

$chartname="chart1";
?>



<div id="chart1" style="height:400px; width:100%;"></div>


    <style type="text/css">
        #<?php echo $chartname; ?> .jqplot-point-label {
          color:#666666;
          font-size:14px;
        }                   
    </style>    
    <script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    function sec_to_str(seconds, format)
    {
        var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        if(hours<10)
            hours="0"+hours;

        var minutes = Math.floor((seconds/ 60) % 60);
        if(minutes<10)
            minutes="0"+minutes;

        var seconds = seconds % 60;
        if(seconds<10)
            seconds="0"+seconds;

        //check given format 
        // format can be     H,     H:i,    H:i:s
        if(format=="H")
            var ret=hours;
        else if(format=="H:i")
            var ret=hours+":"+minutes;
        else if (format=="H:i:s" || format=="")
            var ret=hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;

        return ret;
    }   
    $(document).ready(function(){

        <?php
                $js_array = json_encode($tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['manhours']);
                echo "var manhours = ". $js_array . ";\n";
                $w=json_encode($tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['assignmenthours']);
                echo "var assignmenthours = ". $w . ";\n";
                $t=json_encode($tot_week_manhours_vs_assignmenthours['ticks']);
                echo "var ticks = ". $t . ";\n";
        ?>

        var s1= new Array();
        for (var k in manhours){
            if (manhours.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                 //alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + manhours[k]);
                 s1.push(manhours[k]);
            }
        }

        var s2= new Array();
        for (var j in assignmenthours){
            if (assignmenthours.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                 //alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + manhours[k]);
                 s2.push(assignmenthours[j]);
            }
        }       

        // Can specify a custom tick Array.
        // Ticks should match up one for each y value (category) in the series.
       // var ticks = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'August'];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2], {
            // The "seriesDefaults" option is an options object that will
            // be applied to all series in the chart.
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
               pointLabels: { show: true },
                rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true}
            },
            // Custom labels for the series are specified with the "label"
            // option on the series option.  Here a series option object
            // is specified for each series.
            series:[
                {label:'Man-uren'},
                {label:'Opdracht uren'}
            ],
            // Show the legend and put it outside the grid, but inside the
            // plot container, shrinking the grid to accomodate the legend.
            // A value of "outside" would not shrink the grid and allow
            // the legend to overflow the container.
            legend: {
                show:true,
                placement: 'inside',
                rendererOptions: {
                    numberRows: 1
                },
                location:'ne',
                marginTop: '15px',
                marginRight: '30px'
            },
            axes: {
                // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: ticks
                },
                // Pad the y axis just a little so bars can get close to, but
                // not touch, the grid boundaries.  1.2 is the default padding.
                yaxis: {
                  tickRenderer: $.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer,
                  tickOptions: {
                    formatter: function(format, value) { 
                        var timestring=sec_to_str(value, "H:i");
                        return timestring; 
                        } 
                  }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```